# Undefined variable $daten a kind of ErrorException

Tags: laravel

this is my laravel project, the is a problem named undefined variable
it is funny I think the route is ok and Controller is also fine

route

```
Auth::routes();


Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home')->middleware('auth')->middleware('assign');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/groupchat', 'PagesController@getGroupchatPage')->name('groupchat')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/groupsearch', 'PagesController@getGroupsearchPage')->name('groupsearch')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/statistics', 'PagesController@getStatisticsPage')->name('statistics')->middleware('auth');
//Route::get('/author_views.statisticsA', 'PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin')->name('statisticsA')->middleware('auth');

// Routes for SQL Controller Querys
Route::get('/getQuestions/{id}', 'QuestionsController@getQuestions');
Route::get('/getChapterQuestions/{id}', 'QuestionsController@getChapterQuestions');
Route::get('/getAnswers/{id}', 'AnswersController@getAnswers');
Route::get('/getChapters/{id}', 'ChaptersController@getChapters');
Route::get('/countMembers/{id}', 'GroupsMembersController@countMembers');
Route::get('/getGroupMembers/{id}', 'GroupsMembersController@getGroupMembers');
Route::get('/getGroups/{id}', 'GroupsController@getGroups');
Route::get('/groupChapters/{id}', 'GroupsChaptersController@groupChapters');
Route::get('/getChaptersAndGroup/{id}', 'ChaptersController@getChaptersAndGroup');
Route::get('/getGroupsChaptersMembersKombined/{id}', 'ChaptersController@getGroupsChaptersMembersKombined');

// 28.06.2021
Route::get('/statistics', 'StatisticsController@statistic');
Route::get('/statisticsA', 'StatisticsController@statisticA');

Route::get('/admin', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getAdminPage',
    'as' => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Admin'],
])->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/admin_assign', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@postAdminAssignRoles',
    'as' => 'admin_assign',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Admin'],
])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/statisticsA', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin',
    'as' => 'statisticsA',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Author','Admin']
])->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/eventA', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getEventAdmin',
    'as' => 'eventA',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Author','Admin'],
])->middleware('auth');
```

and my blade

```
@extends('layouts.appAuthor')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">              
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('DozentAnsicht') }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <table id="statisticforteacher" class="table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>FrageBezeichnung</th>
                            <th>Kapitel</th>
                            <th>richtige Antwort</th>
                            <th>falsche Antwort</th>
                            <th>Richtige Rate</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($daten as $value)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$value -> Id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> FrageBezeichnung}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> Kapitel}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> richtigeAntwort}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> falscheAntwort}}</td>
                                <td>{{$value -> richtigeRate}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach                   
                        </tbody>                                           
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I want to show the table in the view, but it didn't work in statisticA but it works in statistic
I don't know what happen

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StatisticsController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function statistic(){
        $data =DB::table('statisticforteacher') -> get();
        return view('/statistics',compact('data'));
    }

    public function statisticA(){
        $daten =DB::table('statisticforteacher') -> get();
        return view('/statisticsA',compact('daten'));
    }
}
```

has anyone a idea?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan view:clear`? Also you have this route `Route::get('/statistics', 'PagesController@getStatisticsPage')->name('statistics')->middleware('auth');` taking over `Route::get('/statistics', 'StatisticsController@statistic');`

Comment: Also you can try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: thanks to your code, now all route couldn't be loaded, it is a bad idea

Comment: What code are you referring about? `php artisan route:clear` only clear the cache of your routes

Comment: In fact that might be a good thing, if after clearing the cache you have other issues, it mean you're on the right path.

Comment: ok, but it still don't solve the undefined variable error, I don't know why

Comment: Can you try `dd($daten)` in your controller to see if you're hitting the right method?

Comment: I tried, but still the same errror

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question? (In Laravel.log)

Comment: Also, I don't think `view('/statisticsA')` is valid. It's usually `view('statisticsA')` without the `/` and then you complete with `.` (dot) for the folder / views `folder.view`

Comment: ye, but the way u talk about which I have already tried, and I make a lot of works, tried so many solutions, include view('statisticsA') all didn't work, I don't know what's wrong with my code

Comment: Can you please, share the stacktrace or the Flare error report?

Answer (score 0):

You have in route file two different routes with same url but different controllers. As in order when Laravel read the file, get the last matched route, for that reason you have the issue. So, fix your routes statements and must work

```
Route::get('/statisticsA', 'StatisticsController@statisticA');

Route::get('/statisticsA', [
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getStatisticsAdmin',
    'as' => 'statisticsA',
    'middleware' => 'roles',
    'roles' => ['Author','Admin']
])->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: _Laravel read the file, get the last matched route_ I'm almost certain, it takes the first matching route. Is that an assumption? I don't have an environment on hand to verify.

Comment: yes, it's an assumption of the logic of sintax parser, not about how Laravel resolve this. If this loose focus or make wrong the answer of the issue, feel free of give yours

Comment: but the view '/statistics' also have different controllers but same url , and it works only in view '/statisticsA' didn't work

Comment: @Prospero I don't think it makes loose the focus or it makes the whole answer wrong. And since I don't see anything wrong in the question, except the route duplications that seems smeely. It still good to explore all the possible solutions.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I agree, I prefer solutions. So in that way, I think duplicate urls can affect the requests, just depends if you make call by the route name or for http